# JSON Spring Web MVC Conversion : (Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.isMapLikeType()Z]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Facing issue while converting to json format, seems to be like jar confict). Below mentioned is my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.fg
    prjSpringMVC
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    prjSpringMVC Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        3.0.5.RELEASE
    
    
        
            junit
            junit
            3.8.1
            test
        
        
            org.springframework
            spring-context
            ${spring.version}
        
        
            org.springframework
            spring-webmvc
            ${spring.version}

```
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>prjSpringMVC</finalName>
</build>
```

Any help / revert appreciated pls.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Still Not working. my understanding is mapper-asl having dependent jar of core-asl. it is

Comment: Still Not Working. Same Error. I think we have the class required but the version is not correct.